# Python 3 and Ubuntu 16: I am unable to install pdfminer in Anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, pdfminer

I have been trying to install pdfminer in Anaconda for about half an hour and I only can see the message at the Terminal "Solving environment".

I am using

```
conda install -c conda-forge pdfminer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried turning off your firewall?

Comment: @DocDriven I dont think I have a firewall in Ubuntu. Is there anyway to know about this?

Comment: There is the ``ufw`` (Uncomplicated Firewall) package, which basically is an interface to ``iptables``. I don't know if you are using it, but if so, turning it off is worth trying.

Comment: @DocDriven It is turned off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discover that there is a more recent library called pdfminer.six, which I was able to install in Anaconda.

When you try to google it, you find

```
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pdfminer
```

which tells you to install

```
 conda install -c conda-forge pdfminer
```

The correct should be

```
 conda install -c conda-forge pdfminer.six
```